# In Android, can I use image from assets in layout xml? 

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

Currently am loading image from drawable resource-

```
<ImageView 
       android:id="@+id/stestImg"
       android:src="@drawable/testImg"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

can I use image from assets here, directly to the layout XML? Do I need to do any coding for that! Please help.

Comment: I think, resources from 'drawable' can be accessed from XML.

Comment: Hi. need to load from asset. Any code example is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**you can do it by this way ::**

```
ImageView i;
Bitmap bm = getBitmapFromAsset("pic1.png");
i = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
i.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

**Call method ::**

```
private Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(String strName) throws IOException
{
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    InputStream istr = assetManager.open(strName);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
    return bitmap;
 }
```

Comment: i have around 150 images and i need to load all images from assets folder so how can i load all images from assets can someone pls help me

Comment: @user3233280 why do you required to load its from assets instread of Sdcard is also option