# access images from assets folder with a button click

Tags: java, android, imageview, assets, buttonclick

So right now i am using this in my code. But now i am storing them in the assets folder and i need help on how to display a different image when you click the next or previous button. So basically i would have a certain amount of pictures in the assets folder and then two button a next and back to scroll through the images. How would i do this? Thanks

```
private int [] images = {R.drawable.airplane, R.drawable.bike, R.drawable.boat,
    R.drawable.bus2,R.drawable.car,R.drawable.train};
```

Comment: You can use a hashmap. With R.drawable.airplane as the key. And the value would be the string.

Comment: can you explain hashmap? I have never used it before..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can save your strings in a resource file. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- single string -->
    <string name="hello">Hello World</string>

    <!-- multiple strings as an array -->
    <string-array name="hello_array">
        <item>hello</item>
        <item>android</item>
        <item>world</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

and later retrieve their references in your code as `R.string.hello` or `R.array.hello_array` respectively.

For more info, refer to [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html) and [this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-string/) guide.

Comment: what if i have an array of strings? like 6 strings and i want to display them in the order that i put them?

Comment: Yes, then you need to use `string-array`. Please refer to [this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-string/) guide

Answer (score 0):

You can have it like this, use [HashMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html).

```
HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
map.put(R.drawable.airplane, "Airplane");
```

then you can get the appropriate String by

```
String whatString = map.get(R.drawable.airplane);
```

Comment: I'm still having some trouble grasping it.. Is it possible to show me one example of how it's done?

Comment: @Dan What part did you had trouble?

Comment: hey Law i decided not to do that anymore can you help me on other problems? like making a button click to retrieve images from the asset folder? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Dan I recommend ask a question about it here, because I think it is much better.

Comment: hi @Law I revised my original question on the top. Hopefully it's clear to understand what i want to do now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7776445/in-android-can-i-use-image-from-assets-in-layout-xml

Comment: Hey @Dan hopefully you can get an idea from that link above. You can just use a single ImageView.

Comment: Thanks! will give it a try and let you know.