# Button click or swipe to retrieve image from assets folder

Tags: android, button, imageview, android-assets, swipe-gesture

I was wondering if it was possible to swipe or click a button to scroll between images stored in the assets folder? I want a previous and next button to go back and forth between the images. I have no idea how to start so some guidance would be helpful.

Comment: google Android ViewPager.

Comment: but how will i get the images from the assets folder? that is the problem that i am having. I have 6 images and plan to add more in the future

Comment: A small search could give you this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7776445/in-android-can-i-use-image-from-assets-in-layout-xml

Comment: not sure where you send me but that question was different from what i want to do.